# Do any known deobfuscateors work on Agile.net 6.4?

Tags: deobfuscation

As a company we are going to start obfuscating our released binaries, so far the best front runner we have found has been Agile.net 6.4.

I took one of our binaries we obfuscated with the trial version of 6.4 and was not able to re-fill the method bodies using the latest development snapshot (from 9/8/2016) of de4dot. It appears that the highest version it supports is Agile.net 6.3.

Are there any known deobfuscators in the wild that can deobfuscate Agile.net 6.4? Knowing that there are no current deobfucators would put it in the definite lead of going from trial to purchasing a full licence.